Amazon Unauthorized Access to requested resource is denied
I am trying form few days used chatGPT also but still no luck i am getting given error
here is the error what i am getting
   GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException 

  Client error: `GET https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/inventory/v1/sku?sellerId=XXX&marketplaceId=XXX` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "Unauthorized",
      "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
      "d (truncated...)

I tried everything it gets access_token correctly my AmazonSPAPIService given below
here is my get access token request
given below my file
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Aws\Sdk;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Inventory;
use App\Models\Gallery;
use App\Models\Order;

class AmazonSPAPIService
{
    protected $httpClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->httpClient = new Client();
    }

    // Get access token for a user
    public function getAccessToken($userId)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                'refresh_token' => $user->amazon_credential->amazon_refresh_token,
                'client_id' => $user->amazon_credential->amazon_client_id,
                'client_secret' => $user->amazon_credential->amazon_client_secret,
                'endpoints_versions' => [
                    'reports' => '2021-06-30' // Specify the correct endpoint version
                    ]
            ],
        ]);
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        //dd($body);
        return $body['access_token']; // Return the new access token
    }

    // Sync inventory for a specific user
    public function syncInventory($userId)
    {
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken($userId);
        $user = User::find($userId);

        // Request headers
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'x-amz-access-token' => $accessToken,
            'x-amz-date' => gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z')

        ];
        // Fetch inventory data from Amazon SP-API
        $response = $this->httpClient->get("https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/inventory/v1/sku", [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'query' => [
                'sellerId' => $user->amazon_credential->amazon_seller_id,
                'marketplaceId' => 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'
                // Add any other query parameters required by the endpoint
            ]
        ]);
        //dd($response);die;
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        // Process and update inventory in the local system
        foreach ($data['inventory'] as $product) {
            $this->updateInventory($product, $userId);
            $this->syncGalleryImages($product, $userId);
        }
    }

    // Update inventory data
    public function updateInventory($product, $userId)
    {
        Inventory::updateOrCreate(
            ['sku' => $product['sku'], 'user_id' => $userId],
            [
                'name' => $product['name'],
                'category' => $product['category'],
                'price' => $product['price'],
                'qty' => $product['quantity'],
                'status' => $product['status'],
                'description' => $product['description'],
                'featured_image' => $product['featured_image'], // Handle image if available
                'brand' => $product['brand'],
                // Add more fields here as needed
            ]
        );
    }

    // Sync gallery images
    public function syncGalleryImages($product, $userId)
    {
        $galleryImages = $product['images'] ?? [];

        foreach ($galleryImages as $imageUrl) {
            Gallery::updateOrCreate(
                ['related_id' => $product['sku'], 'gallery_type' => 'inventory', 'user_id' => $userId],
                ['image_path' => $imageUrl]
            );
        }
    }
}

will be very thankful if anyone can help me with it
So many things google search chatGPT etc
